# How to achieve the below in scheme language?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am trying to get the below output in scheme language. Could anybody let me know where am I wrong? I want to add `.z` at the end, not getting it. How can I?

code:

```
(define (countup n)

 (define (help i)

  (if (<= i n)

   (cons 's (help (+ i 1)))

  '()))

 (help 1 ) )
```

Input:

```
(countup 4)
```

desired output:

```
'(s s s s .z)
```

but coming output

```
'(s s s s)
```

Comment: Note that the "." is an output artefact - it's how your implementation prints an improper list (one whose last element isn't `'()`).

Answer (score 1):

As @molbdnilo mentioned, it has to with output style of proper (ie, null-terminated) vs improper lists.

```
#lang racket
(cons 's (cons 's (cons 's (cons 's 'z))))            ; => '(s s s s . z)
(cons 's (cons 's (cons 's (cons 's '()))))           ; => '(s s s s)
(cons 's (cons 's (cons 's (cons 's (cons 'z '()))))) ; => '(s s s s z)
```